# What's the difference between Easy and Normal in Murder by Numbers?

Tags: murder-by-numbers

What are the differences between the Easy and Normal difficulty levels in the Picross-like puzzle game Murder by Numbers?

[image: settings menu]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The game explains the difference after you complete the tutorial on a new game:

> Easy: Completed rows are automatically crossed out. Hints are on by default.
>
> Normal: No automatic completion of rows. Hints have to be toggled on.
>
> If this is your first time playing this type of puzzle, we recommend starting on easy. Otherwise, challenge yourself to normal! You can change your difficulty at any time, and cases can always be replayed for a better rank.

Additionally, the difficulty will also affect how many case points you get for solving a puzzle.

[image: difficulty selection screen]

Answer (score 1):

> There are only two difficulty levels in this game. There's "Easy," which gives players hints for each puzzle right away, and it crosses out unused squares once players finish filling in a row. Then, there's "Normal," which just lets players do the puzzle on their own with the option to ask for hints if needed.

[Game Rant](https://gamerant.com/murder-by-numbers-mystery-game-ways-great-improve/#:%7E:text=There%20are%20only%20two%20difficulty,ask%20for%20hints%20if%20needed.)